# How to change an App Service region from Region A to Region B using powershell alone

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I have an app service which I created in Central US. However, I would like instead to have the app service located in West US instead. Can I use powershell alone to make this shift?

I realize I can simply delete the app service and plan, and re-create, but looking for powershell to help me here?

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, Azure now does not allow customers to move their resources form one region to another region. For more details, please refer to the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/923992-cross-region-move-for-azure-resources/suggestions/19224478-change-geographical-region-for-a-given-resource).

Comment: @joey Do you have any other concerns?